# Loading external .swf file in Air application causing looping constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, air, loader

I've never encountered this problem before, it seems really bizarre. I'm building an Air application (straight AS3 no flex) that embeds and displays a .swf file. 
Here is my code:

```
public class Something extends Sprite 
{
    private var loader:Loader;

    public function Something():void 
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        loader = new Loader();
        var appDomain:ApplicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain();
        var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, appDomain);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("test.swf"), context);
        trace("hello");
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
    }

    private function loaded(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace(loader.contentLoaderInfo.sameDomain);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
        addChild(loader.content);
    }
}
```

Not only does this not add the .swf file to the display list like I want it to but it seems to run over and over again. "hello" fills up the output window from the trace statement like it's running every frame.

The code loads a .jpg just fine so it must be a problem specific to flash files. I would think I would get some kind of security error if there was a conflict not this strange looping constructor.

Does anybody have any ideas what is causing this behavior?

UPDATE: I finally found this --
[flash crash when loading external swf (with code example this time around)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151912/flash-crash-when-loading-external-swf-with-code-example-this-time-around)

So I think what was happening is that because both flash files shared the same application domain and they both had "Main.as" as the main class file it was running the constructor over and over again.

I'm still haveing trouble though, I've updated my code above to show my unsuccessful attempts to load the external .swf with a different application domain.

I now get this in the output window:

```
hello
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

It could be possible that you have published this file as "test.swf" and you are loading "test.swf" so you are recursively reloading the same file which is this file?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too, my file is named "TestLoader.swf" not "test.swf". I've tried many different flash files all with different names and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

plase make sure that the main class of your loader doesn't same with main class of your loaded swf